# Get IAM userId from userArn

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

I have a usecase where there are multiple aws accounts sending message to my sqs queue and I want  to uniquely identify who sent what. In the SQS message, I see a `Sender Account ID` which is the userId for the IAM user/role who sent the message.

Is there a way I can convert this userId to userArn so that I can identify, which account the message came from. The only API I see is [GetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html) but it expects authorizartion credentials. I don't want to use the userId as it'll increase the operation overhead on my end to figure out all the userId of all the users/roles Arns who have permission to send message.

```
<User>
  <UserId>AIDACKCEVSQ6C2EXAMPLE</UserId>
  <Path>/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/</Path>
  <UserName>Bob</UserName>
  <Arn>arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/Bob</Arn>
  <CreateDate>2013-10-02T17:01:44Z</CreateDate>
  <PasswordLastUsed>2014-10-10T14:37:51Z</PasswordLastUsed>
</User>
```

This userId is a non read friendly unique identifier present for every user/role. What I want to achieve is the userArn by passing the userId.
[This documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html) provides info about userId.

On a more theoretical note, if I can't get the userArn from userId publically without user credentials, what can be the reasoning behind not providing it.

If we look at one of the responses of getUser API, it looks something like this -

Comment: you're mixing distinct things here.  An Account ID maps to the _account_ of the user/role who sent the message, but does not identify the user/role specifically.  Account != user != role and all these things have distinct ARN format that is not interchangeable.

Comment: Hi @DanielFarrell, maybe my question was not clear. I've updated the question with more info, please have a look.
Othetr thatn that, the logic behind naming it like `Sender Account ID` might be that when an SQS message is sent by a root user of an aws account, in that case, we recieve the 12 digit accountId for the sender account in this attribute.

Answer (score 2):

AWS doesn't really provide details of "who" does things in an AWS Account. If a user has sufficient permissions to execute an API call (eg `SendMessage()` to send a message to an SNS queue), it is the *AWS Account* that actually sends the message, not the individual user.

The same goes for objects stored on Amazon S3 (there is no 'user' who owns the object), and Amazon EC2 instances (there is no "owner" of the instance).

The one place where you can identify who does things is in **AWS CloudTrail**, which provides an audit trail of API calls. It will show each API call, with a timestamp and details of the user who made the request.

In your SQS Message, `Sender Account ID` is the ID of the AWS Account that was used by the sender. It is not an ID of that particular user (just the AWS Account they used).